# I am getting a HTTP Status 500 - JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLExceptionforSQL Cannotopenconnection when deploying my project in tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

How can I clear this exception when running my application at localhost?

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:649)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)

Caused by: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Failed to grow the connection pool
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException.throwAtomikosSQLException(AtomikosSQLException.java:46)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.throwAtomikosSQLException(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:88)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:326)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: com.atomikos.datasource.pool.CreateConnectionException: XAConnectionFactory: failed to create pooled connection - DBMS down or unreachable?
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.createPooledConnection(AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.growPool(ConnectionPool.java:193)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:323)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:469)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:156)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:101)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.createPooledConnection(AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.java:60)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
    ... 106 more
```

Comment: First check the connection--try to connect from native client using the same URL, port, db name and credentials

Comment: Status 500 means internal server error.

Comment: the connection to the database is working fine.

Comment: this description `listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor` says that you use improper SID in connection URL. Could you post full URL string?